# Perl + Translate shell script syntax to perl + regular expression

Tags: perl

In my `/var/tmp` I have the following files:

```
 ls | grep FILE
   AAA-FILE.xml
   BBB-FILE.xml
```

With the following command I cut the first word of the files as follows:

```
ls /var/tmp | grep FILE.xml | sed "s/.FILE.*//"
```

I get:

```
AAA
BBB
```

How can I do the same thing with Perl in order to insert the "AAA" and "BBB" in to
@RESULTS? For example:

```
@RESULTS=perl syntax ...
```

Comment: UUOG: `sed -n "/FILE.xml/s/.FILE.*//p"`

Comment: its not perl please see b0fh answer

Comment: And that's why it's not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep using the existing command, you could do

```
my @results = `ls /var/tmp | grep FILE.xml | sed "s/.FILE.*//"`;
chomp for @results;
```

the chomp is to get rid of the trailing newline.

Without resorting to calling external commands:

```
my @results;
opendir DIR,"/var/tmp" or die "Cannot open dir: $!";
for (readdir DIR) {
    /(.*)-FILE.*/ or next;
    push @results, $1;
}
closedir DIR;
```

Comment: THX very good I choose the second option in my perl script

Comment: something else how to change your syntax in case the "-" not appears for example from AAA1FILE.xml it will return AAA1

Comment: You can replace that `ls|grep|sed` with `sed -ne's/.FILE.*//p' /var/tmp`

Answer (score 2):

`@RESULTS = grep(s[/var/tmp/(.*)-FILE.xml][$1],</var/tmp/*>);`

Answer (score 2):

```
@RESULTS = map /(.*)-FILE\.xml$/, <*-FILE.xml>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@RESULTS = map m#/var/tmp/(.*)-FILE.xml#, </var/tmp/*-FILE.xml>;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nE'next unless s/-FILE.*//; push state @lines, $_; die @lines if eof;' /var/tmp
```